# How do I delete unwanted workflow from the sub folder in Informatica?

Tags: workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I tested on a few workflow processes [Under workflow] and I would like to delete some of the unused ones....but the problem is how do I delete them? I tried deleting from the Repository Manager, but there doesn't seem to be delete button for it......

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the `Delete` key on your keayboard after you select the desired workflow from the `Navigator` window (usually on the left side of the screen in Workflow Manager). A window should pop up asking for a confirmation if you want to delete the object from the Repository.

But indeed - there is no delete button on UI.

Answer (score 0):

Menu | Edit | Delete

would do the trick...